# npm 3.5.3 not working at all after upgrade

Tags: npm

After I upgraded npm to 3.5.3 with

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

on my Linux Mint 17.2 it doesn't work anymore. All the commands return to prompt without any message.

Tried:

```
sudo npm install -g yo
npm version
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235655/node-js-conflicts-sbin-node-vs-usr-bin-node/320271#320271) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/335273/installing-node-js-after-apt-get-install-node/335577#335577) I had to

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs

hash -r   #using bash

node --version   # v0.10.25
```

Answer (score 0):

!! WORK FOR ME !!

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

At this stage you will see that npm will not work, but `sudo npm` is working!

Now you can upgrade normally the npm:

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```